# How do I get Sonic Pi 2.9 working with Pi-DAC+?

Tags: audio, sonic-pi

I have:

- a Raspberry Pi 2
- 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie
- a [Pi-DAC+](http://www.iqaudio.co.uk/home/8-pi-dac-0712411999650.html) board connected - and with headphones plugged in

I [read on Twitter](https://twitter.com/samaaron/status/681596831369936896) that Sonic Pi 2.9 should support this:

> Great news for [@Raspberry_Pi](https://twitter.com/Raspberry_Pi) audiophiles - [@Sonic_Pi](https://twitter.com/Sonic_Pi) v2.9 will support any default audio card out of the box. I recommend the [@IQ_audio](https://twitter.com/IQ_audio) hat.

What are the simplest steps that I can follow to make Sonic Pi 2.9 work with this configuration?

Comment: Could someone with more than 300 rep please add a `sonic-pi` tag?

Comment: Lets give this tag a try. Please feel free to add a tag wiki entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a summary of information in the [IQaudIO PDF user manual](http://www.iqaudio.com/downloads/IQaudIO.pdf), with a slight correction as to how to turn off the built-in-audio - kindly provided by IQaudIO support.

### 1. Edit /boot/config.txt

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Add these lines somewhere:

```
dtoverlay=iqaudio-dacplus
dtoverlay=i2s-mmap
```

Comment out the `dtparam=audio=on` line:

```
# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
```

So it becomes:

```
# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
#dtparam=audio=on
```

(Note that this will disable sound via HDMI and headphone jack on the Pi, which is necessary to get Sonic Pi working via the DAC)

Save the file.

### 2. Reboot

```
sync
sudo reboot
```

### 3. Manually download and run Sonic Pi 2.9

2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie comes with Sonic Pi 2.7, and 2.9 is needed to work with DACs.

I found that `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install sonic-pi` still left me with 2.7, so I did this:

Download and run Sonic Pi 2.9

```
wget http://sonic-pi.net/files/releases/v2.9.0/Sonic-Pi-for-RPi-Jessie-v2.9.0.tgz
tar -xvzf Sonic-Pi-for-RPi-Jessie-v2.9.0.tgz
./sonic-pi-v2.9.0/bin/sonic-pi
```

Sonic Pi 2.9 will then play over the headphones attached to the Pi-DAC+, and it will also control the volume over the headphones.